# Contador de clicks a un enlace en Posts de Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, contador

Estoy necesitando un contador de click en enlaces "wa.me/..." y mostrar el contador en cada publicación.

Tengo un sitio Wordpress, tipo directorio, en el que cada publicación es de un cliente diferente y se quiere hacer un conteo de clicks al enlace a su Whatsapp. Por supuesto que se guarde en base de datos y se muestre públicamente en ese Post.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Y que has probado?, Te invito a leer sobre "Ajax" https://decodecms.com/ajax-en-wordpress-de-manera-correcta/ en WordPress y tambien a leer sobre "Post Meta" https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/ y https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/ Con esos podrias comenzar a hacer pruebas, una vez te topes con un problema de programación puedes volver a esta pregunta y actualizarla, tambien te invito a leer [ask] y como hacer un [example]